# Markov Chains: Limiting probabilities of positive recurrent states sum to one?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I have a question about Markov chains. I am trying to understand the proof of Proposition 2.6 of http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/stochastic-I/stochastic-I-MCII.pdf.

The setting is: we have a *positive recurrent irreducible* Markov chain with a possibly infinite state space. I know how to prove that this Markov chain the long-run probability of being in state $j$ is given by:
$$
\pi_j = \frac{1}{E[\tau_{jj}]},
$$
where $\tau_{jj}$ is a random variable representing the number of transitions between two consecutive visits of state $j$. (The proof is in the notes.)

We want to show that these long-run probabilities form a stationary distribution. *Stationary distribution* means that (a) if we start the Markov chain in a random state according to the stationary distribution, then the distribution for the next state is exactly the stationary distribution again, and (b) it is an actual distribution, i.e., the sum of the $\pi_j$'s is one.

In the case where the chain is null-recurrent, the $\pi_j$'s are zero, and hence they add up to zero. That leads me to the question: **how do we know that the $\pi_j$'s form a distribution, i.e., they add up to one in the above setting?** 
In other words, I want to prove:

> **Theorem**. Consider a positive recurrent Markov chain with a possibly infinite state space. Let $\pi_j$ be as above. Then $\sum\pi_j = 1$.

(**NOTE:** It is not hard to come up with a (reducible) Markov chain that has long-run probabilities that add up to $\frac{1}{2}$. Let the states be $0$, $1$, $2$, $\dots$, let the transitions $0\to 1$ and $0\to 2$ happen with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, and let the transitions $1\to 1$, and $2\to 3$, $3\to 4$, $\dots$ happen with probability $1$. Then all $\pi_1 = \frac{1}{2}$ and all other $\pi_j$'s are zero. So the fact that the chain is *irreducible* is important here.)

Comment: I cannot find it online. Look in your library for Kulkarni "Modeling and Analysis of Stochastic Systems" but First edition! You need exactly Theorem 3.15 in pages 105-107 (if it was not 3 pages long I would post it as an answer). Gl